# How can you avoid trashing backstack entries with popBackStack?

Tags: android

I need to move around from fragment to fragment in my backstack. If I use popbackstack it removes the top stack fragments above the one I'm going too. If I need to get back to a fragment higher up on the stack I can't because it gets removed. How can I retain those upper backstack fragments so I don't lose the data in the fragments? Does getBackStackEntryAt() allow me to jump around the stack without trashing the upper backstack items or do I simply need to do a commit() after I popBackStack(i-1,0)?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly how the back stack is supposed to work. The clue is in the "stack" part of the name. It's a LIFO (last-in, first-out) structure, not a random access one. If you want to jump between entries at random, don't use the back stack to do that. Create a fresh entry on the back stack for each jump, or use action bar tabs or similar. If you describe the relationship between your different fragments, we might be able to suggest how best to implement navigation between them; otherwise, you should follow [the official guidelines](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/index.html).

Comment: The only common thread the fragments share is that they are all writing to the same XML file (DOM). User does data entry in frag1, then user does data entry of a different record type in a different frag. Sometimes the user has to switch back and forth between different frags to do data entry.

Comment: How would you go about saving the data in the fragments without writing to the backstack? Is there another method to save state of fragments?

Comment: Sorry if I've not been clear. You should still `addToBackStack` each `FragmentTransaction`: my point is that if you're jumping to another fragment that's not the one the user wasn't looking at last, you *shouldn't* try to use `popBackStack` to achieve this. If the user has to switch back and forth a lot, it sounds like you have information on different screens that should be on one screen.